# bug scatter plot plotly

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot

I have defined the following arrays:

```
aa=np.random.randn(10)
bb=np.random.randn(10)
cc=['Mean1','Mean2','Mean3','Random1','Random2','Random3','Market1','Market2','Market3','Market4']
srvar=(aa-0.0002)/bb
```

then the following scatter plot:

```
scaplot=go.Figure(
layout=go.Layout(
    template='plotly_dark',title_text='Returns (Values in %)',
    title_font_family='Droid Sarif',title_font_size=35,title_xref='paper',title_xanchor='center',
    title_x=0.5,
    xaxis=dict(color='white',title_text='Std. Deviation',title_font_family='Droid Sarif',title_font_size=22
              ),
    yaxis=dict(color='white',title_text='Weekly Returns',
               title_font_family='Droid Sarif',title_font_size=22
              )
)
)
scaplot.add_trace(go.Scatter(
showlegend=False,mode='markers+text',
x=bb*100,
y=aa*100,
hovertext=['{}'.format(round(i*100,2)) for i in srvar],
textfont_size=11,
hovertemplate=
'<i>Return:</i> %{y:.2f}'+
'<br><i>Std. Dev.:</i> %{x:.2f}</br>'+
'<i>Sharpe R.:</i> %{hovertext} <extra></extra>',
texttemplate=
'<i><b>%{text}</b></i>',
text=['{}{}'.format('' if i[:2] in ['Me','Ma'] else 'Sec: ',i if i[0:2]!='Me' else '') for i in cc],
textposition='bottom center',
marker=dict(
    symbol=104,size=13,color=srvar,cmin=np.amin(srvar),cmax=np.amax(srvar),cmid=np.median(srvar),
    colorscale='jet',showscale=True,line_width=3,
    colorbar=dict(
        tickmode='linear',tick0=np.amin(srvar),dtick=(np.amax(srvar)-np.amin(srvar))/5,ticks='outside',
        tickfont_family='Droid Serif',tickfont_size=15,tickfont_color='white',
        title=dict(
            text=
            '<i>Sharpe Ratio</i>'
            '<br><i>CB</i></br>',
            font_family='Droid Sarif',font_size=27,font_color='white'
        )
    )
)
)
             )
pio.show(scaplot)
```

and everything works perfectly as you can see in the following pic:

[image: scatter]

No complaints so far, BUT when I run the following code:

```
scatter_plot.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        showlegend=False,mode='markers+text',
        x=_sd_*100 if (method=='lp' or method=='bootlp') else sd*100,
        y=temp*100 if (method=='lp' or method=='bootlp') else mean*100,
        hovertext=['{}'.format(round(i*100,2)) for i in sr_var],
        textfont_size=11,
        hovertemplate=
        '<i>Return:</i> %{y:.2f}'+
        '<br><i>Std. Dev.:</i> %{x:.2f}</br>'+
        '<i>Sharpe R.:</i> %{hovertext} <extra></extra>',
        texttemplate=
        '<i><b>%{text}</b></i>',
        text=['{}{}'.format('' if i[:2] in ['Me','Ma'] else 'Sec: ',i if i[0:2]!='Me' else '') for i in dfc] if (method=='lp' or method=='bootlp') else [''],
        textposition='bottom center',
        marker=dict(
            symbol=104,size=13,color=sr_var,
            cmin=np.amin(sr_var),cmax=np.amax(sr_var),cmid=np.median(sr_var),
            colorscale='jet',showscale=True,
            colorbar=dict(
                tickmode='linear',tick0=np.amin(sr_var),dtick=(np.amax(sr_var)-np.amin(sr_var))/5,ticks='outside',
                tickfont_family='Droid Serif',tickfont_size=15,tickfont_color='white',
                title=dict(
                    text=
                    '<i>Sharpe Ratio</i>'
                    '<br><i>CB</i></br>'
                    ,font_family='Droid Sarif',font_size=27,font_color='white'
                )
            )
        )
    )
                          )
    pio.show(scatter_plot)
```

(method is only one str variable that is an input and specifies which method the user wants if lp bootlp or others...)

I get this mess:

[image: second pic]

As you can see, hovertext didnt work, text work for some but overwrote the %{text} variable, the color of all marks is black despite the colorbar shows the scale... so I dont know why it is happening. Could anyone explain what I am missin? I tried many different things and always same result. I would appreciate your time and dedication.